# How do I re-order tabs in user page?

Tags: 7

I'm developing a drupal 7 based website where the user profiles need some modification. Now I need to know how can I re-order tabs in user profile page such as, View, Edit, etc.

i'd like to keep the current tabs, but just reorder them. I'm looking for an easy way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [hook_menu_local_tasks_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_local_tasks_alter/7.x) for example in the bellow example i will change the order between tab 2 and tab 3:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_local_tasks_alter().
 */
function YouModule_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $router_item, $root_path) {
  if (isset($data['tabs'][0]['output'])) {
   $data['tabs'][0]['output'][0]['#weight'] = 0;
   $data['tabs'][0]['output'][1]['#weight'] = 2;
   $data['tabs'][0]['output'][2]['#weight'] = 1;
   $data['tabs'][0]['output'][3]['#weight'] = 3;
   $data['tabs'][0]['output'][4]['#weight'] = 4;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @berramou, Thanks for your quick answer. I'll surely try the method you shared and post an update here. Thanks again for answering my drupal 7 question.

Comment: you are welcome, i have tested it it works, change the weigh as you like will change the order.

Comment: Thanks again, The code is working great. That's what I was looking for.

Comment: i'm glad that help.